# Using np.hstack and vstack returns ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, opencv, stack, axis

I'm currently having the Value error in this line of code

this is the function I created

```
def canny(im=None, sigma=None, scaling=None, vert=None, horz=None):

xscaling = vert
yscaling = horz

hsize = (6 * sigma + 1), (6 * sigma + 1)# The filter size.

gaussian = gauss2D(hsize, sigma)
im = filter2(gaussian, im)# Smoothed image.
#scaling = 0.4
#scaling = tuple(scaling)

im = cv2.resize(im,None, fx=scaling, fy=scaling )  

[rows, cols] = np.shape(im)

im = np.array(im, dtype=float)
print("This is im array")
print(im)
#h =  [  im(:,2:cols)  zeros(rows,1) ] - [  zeros(rows,1)  im(:,1:cols-1)  ];
```

and I'm currently having an error on this line

```
d1 = (np.vstack((np.hstack((im[2:rows,2:cols], np.zeros((rows-1,1))))),np.zeros((1,cols)))) - np.vstack((np.zeros((1,cols)), np.hstack((np.zeros((rows-1,1)),im[1:rows-1,1:cols-1]))))
```

IDLE returns ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: did you check the array dimensions?

Comment: OK, and what's the problem? The error message seems fairly clear about what precondition you have not satisfied... | Also it might be useful to break that ginormous statement into smaller pieces, so it's easier to understand and debug. (Generally, if you have to scroll horizontally to see all the code, you could have written it more legibly.)